# How to get the URL path to a layer in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver

From the Geoserver Layers Preview page, is there a way to get the URL of the services in the 'All Formats' drop-down?

Alternately, is there a way to change which formats are listed in the 'Common Formats' column?

I've been sharing the Layer Preview page to external users as a way to give a quick way to share our data in various formats, but would like to, for example, give the URL for a CSV or SHP rather than send instructions to pull the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The url is specified in the WMS GetMap Request.

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getmap

It is similar to this

```
localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?
request=GetMap
&service=WMS
&version=1.1.1
&layers=topp%3Astates
&srs=EPSG%3A4326
&format=text/csv
```

The formats can be found here:

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html

You can then alter the **outputFormat** paramemeter of the URL to accomodate whatever format you need using the values in the link to the formats above.

(comment from DPSSpatial:)

For me, changing the URL from GeoJSON (easy to access the URL via the Layer Preview page in Geoserver) from:

https://servername.whatever.org/geoserver/dpsworkspace/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=dpsworkspace:Schools_Current&maxFeatures=1000&outputFormat=application%2Fjson

to:

https://servername.whatever.org/geoserver/dpsworkspace/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=dpsworkspace:Schools_Current&maxFeatures=1000&outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP

Answer (score 1):

Nyes...

Looking at the HTML, we see that the URL is generated when selecting an item in the drop down menu. It has 2 base URLs, one for WMS and the other one for WFS, and then it adds the selected output format value to the base URL.

You could keep a list of the available format and replace the format from the *common format* link